# How to sum elements in a column using mysql

Tags: mysql, database

As most of us know database systems has build in aggregate function SUM that takes a column name as parameter and returns the sum of the elements in that column.

I want to know if there is another way to sum the elements of a column using some query.

Please have in mind that i do not want to get as an asnwer to use a stored procedure and a cursor to loop throught the elements and do some calculation.

So... Is there another way to sum elements of a column (without using the build in aggregate function SUM() )

P.S. This question looks weird but i do have a reason to ask it!

Comment: What do you want, _exactly_? Your question seems to be more a statement than anything right now

Comment: Why do you want this?  The aggregate `SUM()` will already be highly optimized by the RDBMS, and can be fully limited by `WHERE`, operate over joins, etc...

Comment: Why do you want another way? Is `SUM()` not working for you? It works in MySQL...

Comment: Because few days ago i asked a complicated question and got no answer. That is why i am asking this question. If i get an answer for this one then i will try to do what i want ( which is something completely different that summing a column elements )

Comment: SUM() is the best, you should love it.

Comment: If you don't get answers try offering a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can create trigger on table, which will do something like:

```
 Update other_table set value=value+NEW.field_have_be_summed where option='sum';
```

But hard to say what exactly you want.

Comment: 10x dude. This one is interesting.

Comment: I want to calculate a geo distance where each element in the column is a point. However i have two columns: Latitude and Longtitude and i want to apply haversine formula on each two rows in thouse columns.

Comment: I am sorry, it is not clear what exactly you want. You can use Sum(a+b) or sum(a*a+b*b) if you need sum of all distances(depend of your formula/algebra used).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
DECLARE v_sum INT

SELECT v_sum = v_sum + intcol As RunningTotal
FROM Table
```

The value of `v_sum` at the end would be the sum of `intcol`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SET @values='SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columnWithNumbers SEPARATOR \'+\')as sumall FROM table';
SET @select = CONCAT('SELECT ', @values); 
PREPARE stmt FROM @select;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Untested.

Or simpler explanation, you copy the results from this query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columnWithNumbers SEPARATOR '+')as sumall FROM table
```

And add a select before and paste the results you just copied in a new query.